# In Xcode UI Test, how can I repeatedly check if an element exists and if so perform an action?

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I’m implementing UI tests. The app makes API calls that could make alerts ( it's a UIView attached to the window ) appear. Of course, these are random/not predictable. If they show up, I have to dismiss them (clicking on the close button). Any idea how to do this? Do I have some event that says that something happened on the UI? I was thinking to have a thread that executes every 0.5 seconds that checks if the dismiss button exists and if so I tap on it.

```
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
        while true
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if(self.app.buttons["NotificationCloseButton"].exists)
                {
                    self.app.buttons["NotificationCloseButton"].tap()
                }
            }
            sleep(5)
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that it causes random crashes: `Neither attributes nor error returned`

Answer (score 3):

There is nice example of how to wait for element to appear on screen [here](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#how-to-wait-for-an-element-to-appear). Here is example of code taken from the link:

```
let nextGame = self.app.staticTexts["Game 4 - Tomorrow"]
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWithObject: nextGame, handler: nil)

app.buttons["Load More Games"].tap()

waitForExpectations(timeout: 5, handler: nil)
XCTAssert(nextGameLabel.exists)
```

Link also provides how to wait for system alert to appear:

```
addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Location Dialog") { (alert) -> Bool in
    alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()
    return true
}

app.buttons["Find Games Nearby?"].tap()
app.tap() // need to interact with the app for the handler to fire
XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["Authorized"].exists)
```